# NSToolbar special area

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4.2, nstoolbar

I like to try to completely take over the area where the NSToolbar resides so I can put my own custom controls, views and background. The advantages of using this area are:

- Any sliding panels appear below the toolbar area instead of just the title bar.
- In Lion, the toolbar area comes down along with the menu bar when the mouse is at the top of the screen.

I have tried using a borderless window, and implementing my own custom views within it but unfortunately I lose the above advantages as well as having a few other minor problems.

My current method is to use the undocumented method '_toolbarView' with the NSToolbar and add my custom view into its subviews. This works fine as I can turn off toolbar customisation. Unfortunately, the size of the toolbar is initialised with the items within that toolbar. Does anyone know if I can change the size of toolbar without adding a fake ToolbarItem?

Maybe there's also a better way of doing this that I am currently unaware of.
Thanks for any suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use any undocumented APIs. Just create a toolbar item with a custom view:

```
- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag {
    NSToolbarItem *item = [[[NSToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier:itemIdentifier] autorelease];
    …
    [item setView:myCustomToolbarView];
    …
}
```

You can control your custom toolbar’s size using the item’s `minSize` and `maxSize` properties (e. g. in your `NSWindowDelegate`’s `-windowDidResize:`).

Remember to also update the toolbar display mode so it doesn't show item labels:

```
[toolbar setDisplayMode: NSToolbarDisplayModeIconOnly];
```

Comment: I think this might be it! Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the nstoolbaritem doesn't go to the edge of the toolbar area. There is always approx 5 pixel padding. Any idea how to get rid of this border?

Comment: I vaguely recall the Panic guys having that problem with Coda. I think there’s no solution (with documented APIs at least). What you could try instead is to use a textured window and set the top content border thickness appropriately (`[window setContentBorderThickness:123.0 forEdge:NSMaxYEdge]`).

Comment: One more thing: If you want to control where sheets (“sliding panels”) appear, use the `NSWindowDelegate` method `-window:willPositionSheet:usingRect:`.