# How to use NSProgressIndicator as NSToolbarItem

Tags: xcode, nstoolbar, nsprogressindicator

How to add NSProgressIndicator(NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle) to toolbar as NSToolbarItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058046/nstoolbar-special-area).  You should be able to create a custom view with a progress indicator, then link it up.